# are fork.. join statements allowed in functions in system verilog?

Tags: function, system-verilog, fork-join

they are definitely allowed in tasks, But I could not find, if they are allowed in functions.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `fork...join_none` is allowed within functions.

A `fork` block can only be used in a function if it is matched with a `join_none`.  The reason is that functions must execute in zero time.  Because a `fork...join_none` will be spawned into a separate thread/process, the function can still complete in zero time.

This is clearly stated in [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) in section **13.4.4 Background processes spawned by function calls**

> Functions shall execute with no delay. Thus, a process calling a function shall return immediately. Statements that do not block shall be allowed inside a function; specifically, nonblocking assignments, event triggers, clocking drives, and `fork - join_none` constructs shall be allowed inside a function.

Comment: Also note the next paragraph in the standard mentions that calling a function with a fork/join_none is only allowed from a thread started an initial or always block. You can't have this kind of function call as part of a port connection, continuous assignment, or static variable initialization. There reason is there is not way to guarantee random stability in these threads, or even predict the number of time these functions get called in a time slot.

Answer (score 0):

My simulation tool allows `fork...join_none` in functions but issues a warning that `fork...join` (and probably `fork...join_any`) will be converted to `begin...end`. I couldn't find anything in the standard about this which most likely is why I don't get a strict compile error.

Be careful as different simulator vendors may implement different rules. In two of the big 3 simulators `fork...join_none` in functions definitely works. `fork...join/join_any` doesn't make sense in the context of a function so I would avoid it altogether.